# How can I clear all children nodes of a data node, but NOT delete the data node itself in zookeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a znode: `/test`

And `/test` has two children nodes: `/test/data1`, `/test/data2`

How can I delete `/test/data1` and `/test/data2`, but at the same time, NOT delete the node `/test`?

Comment: Are you using zkCli or an API for issuing commands to ZooKeeper?

Comment: Yes, I use zkCli, like this: `zkCli.sh -server xxx deleteall /test`

Answer (score 0):

You can execute something like the following:

```sh
zkCli.sh -server xxx ls /test | \ 
grep  "^\[" | \
grep -o -P  "\w*" | \ 
while read znode ; do zkCli.sh -server xxx delete /test/$znode ; done
```

This is only using zkCli.sh and bash commands but is not optimal because it connects to the ZooKeeper server multiple times (one for each direct child deletion + one to fetch the children list). A more straightforward approach would be to use a ZooKeeper client library like kazoo or ZooKeeper Java API for such a task.